# Is this hardware will work with Android Emulator and Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, android-emulator

It is a hardware question but kids from PC forum won't know the answer.

This time I have different problem. I need to buy a computer that will support Windows Phone Emulator(needs DirectX11 or 10) and virtual Windows(vmWare). This one is really cheap it is about 380$ but I am worried if it will handle the Android and Windows Phone emulator well.

LCD - 15.6"
AMD E E300 (1.3 GHz, 1MB )
RAM - 4 GB
HDD - 320 GB
AMD Radeon HD 6310M
http://www.komputronik.pl/index.php/product/171620/Komputery/Laptopy_i_netbooki/Toshiba_Satellite_C660D_1H2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WindowsPhone 7** are of two types WP 512 and WP 256.
WP 512 means it runs with 512MB or ram and same for WP7 256.
WP emulator takes more memory but run very smoothly on my PC.
Upto 1 Gb by WP-512 and 600MB by WP-256 emulator

**Android** run very slow on my pc and takes minutes to start. It takes les memory approx 350MB but consume must CPU cycles.

**MY PC configuration is:

Windows 7 Professional - 32bit

Intel i3 @ 3.07GHz processor and 4MB Cache

On board graphics card 

4GB RAM

500GB HDD**